# MySQL performance?

Tags: mysql, debian

I have 2 main tables on the server, with the same structure and data (the only difference is in the names of the tables).

Table #1:214million rows, size 40GB (25gb indexes)

Table #2:26million rows, size 5.5GB (3.5gb indexes)

The first problem. Everything works very quickly when there is a cache in memory. If i clean cache or reboot the server, then mysql queries is very slow. Debian 8 jessie. MySQL stores indexes in memory and takes it as a cache, always? Because after some manipulations, the select queries is very fast. What manipulations need to be done to make the server fly:

If I using duplicate of table #1, then during its execution, as I understand it, a read operation occurs and at the same time the information is cached into memory. Here is a **free -m** screen at the moment of launching a duplicate table.

```
root@ns344370:~# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        128965      76802      52163         31         61      21714
-/+ buffers/cache:      55026      73939
Swap:        56141          0      56141
```

The result, when the duplicate table was created:

```
root@ns344370:~# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        128965     126414       2551         31         49      65426
-/+ buffers/cache:      60938      68027
Swap:        56141          0      56141
```

50GB of RAM under the cache. Execution of the query before the duplicate table 105 seconds:

```
# Query_time: 105.469931  Lock_time: 0.000180 Rows_sent: 41041  Rows_examined: 2097994
SET timestamp=1539135133;
SELECT SQL_CACHE `id`, `currency`, `handLimit`, `date`, `pp1` AS `profit`,`psd1` AS `isSD` FROM `ps_hands` WHERE `p1` = '274606' AND (`date` >= '2018-10-01' AND `date` <= '2018-10-10') 
UNION ALL (SELECT `id`, `currency`, `handLimit`, `date`, `pp2` AS `profit`, `psd2` AS `isSD` FROM `ps_hands` WHERE `p2` = '274606' AND (`date` >= '2018-10-01' AND `date` <= '2018-10-10')) 
UNION ALL (SELECT `id`, `currency`, `handLimit`, `date`, `pp3` AS `profit`, `psd3` AS `isSD` FROM `ps_hands` WHERE `p3` = '274606' AND (`date` >= '2018-10-01' AND `date` <= '2018-10-10')) 
UNION ALL (SELECT `id`, `currency`, `handLimit`, `date`, `pp4` AS `profit`, `psd4` AS `isSD` FROM `ps_hands` WHERE `p4` = '274606' AND (`date` >= '2018-10-01' AND `date` <= '2018-10-10')) 
UNION ALL (SELECT `id`, `currency`, `handLimit`, `date`, `pp5` AS `profit`, `psd5` AS `isSD` FROM `ps_hands` WHERE `p5` = '274606' AND (`date` >= '2018-10-01' AND `date` <= '2018-10-10')) 
UNION ALL (SELECT `id`, `currency`, `handLimit`, `date`, `pp6` AS `profit`, `psd6` AS `isSD` FROM `ps_hands` WHERE `p6` = '274606' AND (`date` >= '2018-10-01' AND `date` <= '2018-10-10')) 
UNION ALL (SELECT `id`, `currency`, `handLimit`, `date`, `pp7` AS `profit`, `psd7` AS `isSD` FROM `ps_hands` WHERE `p7` = '274606' AND (`date` >= '2018-10-01' AND `date` <= '2018-10-10')) 
UNION ALL (SELECT `id`, `currency`, `handLimit`, `date`, `pp8` AS `profit`, `psd8` AS `isSD` FROM `ps_hands` WHERE `p8` = '274606' AND (`date` >= '2018-10-01' AND `date` <= '2018-10-10')) 
UNION ALL (SELECT `id`, `currency`, `handLimit`, `date`, `pp9` AS `profit`, `psd9` AS `isSD` FROM `ps_hands` WHERE `p9` = '274606' AND (`date` >= '2018-10-01' AND `date` <= '2018-10-10')) 
ORDER BY `id` ASC;
```

After the duplicate table its 0.2 seconds instead 105 secs. I am thinking of changing the disk from SSHD to NVMe M2 (5x faster). But I will have another 4-5 tables of 50GB each, in this case, I just do not have enough RAM. How to be?
I have 128GB RAM. In addition to this project, there is one more project. On which 50GB are allocated. The rest is used for this project and MySQL.
I use MyISAM and not InnoDB, because on the site only selects and inserts operations. InnoDB is 20 times slower, checked on a home machine, too, with an M.2 disk.... And here is mysql config file:

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
query_cache_type = DEMAND

key_buffer_size = 55G
sort_buffer_size = 512M
read_buffer_size = 128M

max_allowed_packet = 32M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 4096

#MySQL Tuner
max_heap_table_size = 128M
tmp_table_size = 128M
table_open_cache = 4096

myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 2000
table_cache            = 2048
thread_concurrency     = 17
query_cache_limit   = 128M
query_cache_size  = 256M

log_slow_queries  = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time   = 1
#log-queries-not-using-indexes

expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 256M
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Any ideas? Please.

Table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `ps_hands` (
  `id` bigint(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `currency` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `handLimit` smallint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `maxPlayers` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `p1` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p2` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p3` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p4` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p5` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p6` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p7` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p8` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p9` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pp1` mediumint(7) NOT NULL,
  `pp2` mediumint(7) NOT NULL,
  `pp3` mediumint(7) NOT NULL,
  `pp4` mediumint(7) NOT NULL,
  `pp5` mediumint(7) NOT NULL,
  `pp6` mediumint(7) NOT NULL,
  `pp7` mediumint(7) NOT NULL,
  `pp8` mediumint(7) NOT NULL,
  `pp9` mediumint(7) NOT NULL,
  `psd1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `psd2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `psd3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `psd4` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `psd5` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `psd6` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `psd7` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `psd8` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `psd9` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `maxPlayers` (`maxPlayers`),
  KEY `p1_handLimit` (`p1`,`handLimit`),
  KEY `p2_handLimit` (`p2`,`handLimit`),
  KEY `p3_handLimit` (`p3`,`handLimit`),
  KEY `p4_handLimit` (`p4`,`handLimit`),
  KEY `p5_handLimit` (`p5`,`handLimit`),
  KEY `p6_handLimit` (`p6`,`handLimit`),
  KEY `p7_handLimit` (`p7`,`handLimit`),
  KEY `p8_handLimit` (`p8`,`handLimit`),
  KEY `p9_handLimit` (`p9`,`handLimit`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Query explain:

```
+------+--------------+--------------------------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+--------+----------------+
| id   | select_type  | table                    | type | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra          |
+------+--------------+--------------------------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+--------+----------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | ps_hands                 | ref  | p1_handLimit  | p1_handLimit | 3       | const | 182239 | Using where    |
|    2 | UNION        | ps_hands                 | ref  | p2_handLimit  | p2_handLimit | 3       | const | 290077 | Using where    |
|    3 | UNION        | ps_hands                 | ref  | p3_handLimit  | p3_handLimit | 3       | const | 273151 | Using where    |
|    4 | UNION        | ps_hands                 | ref  | p4_handLimit  | p4_handLimit | 3       | const | 248191 | Using where    |
|    5 | UNION        | ps_hands                 | ref  | p5_handLimit  | p5_handLimit | 3       | const | 255685 | Using where    |
|    6 | UNION        | ps_hands                 | ref  | p6_handLimit  | p6_handLimit | 3       | const | 362813 | Using where    |
|    7 | UNION        | ps_hands                 | ref  | p7_handLimit  | p7_handLimit | 3       | const | 358672 | Using where    |
|    8 | UNION        | ps_hands                 | ref  | p8_handLimit  | p8_handLimit | 3       | const | 264515 | Using where    |
|    9 | UNION        | ps_hands                 | ref  | p9_handLimit  | p9_handLimit | 3       | const | 221512 | Using where    |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL  | NULL   | Using filesort |
+------+--------------+--------------------------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+--------+----------------+
```

Comment: If you want to improve the performance by tuning SQL queries, then this is the place to post your slow SQL query. However, if SQL programming is just a black box to you and you only want to tune the infrastructure of the database, then you should post this question in dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @TheImpaler , im sorry, added query to post.

Comment: Is there an index on the `date` field?

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, making sure there is an index on (or starting with) the `date` field could help.
Also, since you probably won't be able to benefit from an index involving the `p#` fields, you could try a non-UNION version of the query like this

```
SELECT `id`, `currency`, `handLimit`, `date`
   , CASE 
     WHEN `p1` = '274606' THEN `pp1`
     WHEN `p2` = '274606' THEN `pp2`
     -- and so on ...
     END AS `profit`
   , CASE 
     WHEN `p1` = '274606' THEN `psd1`
     WHEN `p2` = '274606' THEN `psd2`
     -- and so on ...
     END AS AS `isSD` 
FROM `ps_hands` 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-10'
   AND '274606' IN (`p1`,`p2`,`p3`,`p4`,`p5`,`p6`,`p7`,`p8`,`p9`)
ORDER BY `id` ASC;
```

---

EDIT/WARNING: If the same row can have more than one p# with the same value, the above will not work though; instead the expressions for `profit` and `isSD` will need to be adjusted (perhaps adding the pp# values together?)... and you would still not get a separate result row for each column match.

---

Edit#2: Separate compound indexes `(p#, date)` or `(date, p#)` for each p# should help your original query significantly. I would first try just a single `date` index first though, and if that is not performant enough go with the `(date, p#)` compound indexes. For your query, the `(date, p#)` indexes probably wouldn't work much better than the `(p#, date)` ones, but they will effectively give you a `date` index that other queries can take advantage of.

Comment: I added again Table DDL, and query explain to #1 post. Now try to check what you wrote

Comment: Uueerdo, thank you, i need time for testing changes. I'll tell the results when I'm done testing.

Comment: Uueerdo, first option not working for me, i have same values in p1-p9 , its a player IDs. And it also seems to me that there is no point in indexing a field with a date. I using date in each row... And most often I get the data exactly by p1-p9 or p1-p9 and handLimit.

Comment: Why would you think using date in each row would make an index not helpful? An index on date is important because it is your most likely path to reducing the amount of rows evaluated by the WHERE. Unless you have more p values than days, date is more important to have an index on than the p columns...and I mean having the same values for different p# fields in the same row.

Comment: Uueerdo, 786340 rows in set - its query SELECT date FROM ps_hands WHERE date = '2018-05-05'; That is, in one day so many entries (786k). And now imagine the index date .. A player is supposed to have a total of 300 thousand entries per year (as example). And we have to process so many dates. It will be very hard for the server.

Comment: I am not sure why you think indexing the date would be hard for the server when you have 9 separate indexes on the p# fields already, but I could be misunderstanding what you are trying to say. ...but to refer back your earlier comment, the handlimit portion of your index does little, if anything, to help your query's performance.

Comment: Uueerdo, ok. Do I need to make a composite index? Not single?

Comment: I mean: (p1,date); (p2,date); etc. instead p1; date; p2; date; etc.

Comment: I would try just a simple `date` index first; if that doesn't help much, then try composite indexes on `(date, p1)`, `(date, p2)`, etc...  and with the date index created, check my query performance (if it similar enough results) vs yours. The one I supplied should benefit much more from it, where yours may benefit more from the composite ones.